# Is there the determinant equality that $|[M_1 M_2;M_3 M_4]|=|[M_1 M_2^T;M_3 M_4^T]|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is there
$$\left|\begin{matrix}M_1 &M_2\\M_3 &M_4\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}M_1 &M_2^T\\M_3 &M_4^T\end{matrix}\right|,$$
where $M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4$ are all $n$-by-$n$ matrices, $M^T$ stands for the transpose of matrix $M$, $|M|$ stands for the determinant of $M$?

It follows from the question below:

Let $M$ and $A$ be $2n$-by-$2n$ matrices s.t.

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&E\\-E &0\end{matrix}\right],$$
$$M^TAM=A,$$
where $E$ is the identity matrix. Prove that $|M|=1$.

Letting $M=\left[\begin{matrix} M_1&M_2\\M_3&M_4\end{matrix}\right]$, I calculated that $M_1^TM_4-M_3^TM_2=E$, hence it suffices to show the equality above.

I'd be grateful if anybody could provide any hint, method or a complete solution.

Comment: False for $n=1$. The "question below" is a consequence of the fact that $\operatorname{Pf}\left(M^TAM\right) = \det M \cdot \operatorname{Pf}A$ for any alternating (i.e., skew-symmetric with zero diagonal) matrix $A$ and any matrix $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider 
$$
M_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\quad
M_2 = M_2^T = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\quad
M_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\quad
M_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you will get
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 1,
$$
while 
$
M_4^T = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
and
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 0,
$$
thus no.

Comment: Careful: Transposing $I$ gives you still $I$.

Comment: ups, made an error

Comment: Yeah...A friend of mine also told me a counterexample a few minutes ago.